# Detecting a full HTML5 storage (ng-storage)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I'm using ng-storage to store JSON that keeps track of checked checkboxes and various form values (lot of forms) in case of refresh. There is a certain scenario in which local storage becomes full and reloading a page results in:

**Bad Message 431 reason: Request Header Fields Too Large**

I have found no way to capture and handle this response to clear my storage in this scenario. If it helps this is my service:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('CookieService', function($localStorage, SharedService) {
    $localStorage[SharedService.activeOffer.id] = $localStorage[SharedService.activeOffer.id] || {};
    var localStorage = $localStorage[SharedService.activeOffer.id];

    return {
      localStorage: localStorage,
      setSession: function(id, data) {
        checkLocalStorageUsage();
        if (typeof data != "string") {
          data = JSON.stringify(data);
        }
        localStorage[id] = data;
      },
      getSession: function(id) {
        if (localStorage[id]) {
          return JSON.parse(localStorage[id]);
        }
      },
      checkSession: function(id) {
        return (!!(localStorage[id] && localStorage[id].length));
      },
      removeSession: function(id) {
        delete localStorage[id];
      },
      removeAllSessions: function(id) {
        $localStorage.$reset();
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a try-catch to check if the value was added or not, something like :

```
function addValueToLocalstorage(key, value) {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the function return **false** and the localstorage is active, then there are a lot de chances that this is because you reached the quota.
You could try to parse de string of the error message in the catch, but it is not persistent between browsers.